# searching a class hierarchy in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, search, xcode4

Is there an easy way to search a class and its subclasses in Xcode 4?

EDIT: to clarify, for example I might want to find every implementation of a method whose name contains the word "deep" in the class and its subclasses.

Comment: You can open the Symbol navigator with Cmd+2, not sure if that's what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a global search of your project (CMD+Shift+F) to find all methods containing the name that you want.